# Using FireFox with Android WebView

Tags: android, xml, android-webview

I am creating a simple WebView app for my customers which pulls a web-portal to the app.  The .apk is compiled and works on older versions of Android; however, I am experiencing issues with any OS version 3.x.x or higher; where the native Android Browser returns: "ERROR 500
HTTP Web Server: Invalid POST Request Exception".

To bypass this error outside of any apps, the FireFox browser works as intended without returning any errors.

**Question**- Is there an easy way to force the WebView app to retrieve from FireFox instead of the native browser?

I have found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788395/in-android-how-can-i-force-open-a-uri-using-a-specific-browser-without-popping) that lists a call change as follows:

```
String packageName = "com.android.browser";  
String className = "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity";  
Intent internetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
internetIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);  
internetIntent.setClassName(packageName, className);  
startActivity(internetIntent);
```

Being new to 'coding' scene, I am at a loss, as I do not have any calls (scripts?) in my manifest file that can be edited in this way.

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to implement your own `WebView` that uses Firefox's rendering engine, which would be [very difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352654/use-firefox-as-render-engine-for-android-webview). If you have some control over the server side (the web portal) and can view the logs, the best course of action is probably to understand why the server is rejecting POST requests from devices running Android 3.x and higher.

Comment: The issue with the server is actually a Domino error that was supposed to be fixed in 8.5.2 but is still corrupt as of 8.5.3.

Comment: Using the link I provided above, is there no way to add this code to mine?

Comment: If you want to launch the Firefox app to view the page, then you could adapt that code to do so. It's not currently possible (without huge effort) to embed a Firefox-based `WebView` in your own app.